# How many bricks are used in paving the patio in this math question?

Tags: geometry, logarithms, arithmetic

The following math problem is from Mathematics Olympiad for primary school students. I calculated the number of bricks needed as 961 but the key doesn't give that number. Please help see whether I was wrong and if so, what is the right answer. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: $\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{999}{3}}\right\rfloor^2\cdot 3$?

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeyBurdin. I'm sorry that I'm not familiar with the math notation in your formula here. Can you further explain how the formula calculates the result and why the formula can solve the question? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say bricks are rectangles $1\times 3$ or can be rotated to $3\times 1$, so that $3$ bricks form a square $3\times 3$.
So, if Alex wants that pattern as the displayed, she should take $m\times m$ of $3\times 3$ squares of bricks, which is $3m^2$ ones.
So the task is to find maximal integer $m$ for that $3m^2\le 999$ holds.
That is $$m^2\le \frac{999}{3}$$ $$m\le \sqrt{\frac{999}{3}}$$ where $\sqrt{.}$ is [square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root) and $m$ maximal integer, so [wiki: Floor and ceiling functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) reads

> In mathematics and computer science, the **floor function** is the function that takes as input a real number $x$ and gives as output the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, denoted $\operatorname{floor}(x) = \lfloor x\rfloor$.

So $m=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{999}{3}}\right\rfloor$ and the number of blocks is $3m^2=3\left\lfloor\sqrt{\frac{999}{3}}\right\rfloor^2=972$

Comment: that's right. I didn't think about the three small rectangles in each unit square. Thank you for your help.